# Testing newly installed version of QGIS with custom settings

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, installation

Each time when my organization updates/migrates to the latest QGIS either a regular release or a LTR, how could I ensure that it adopts all the customized adjustments&settings from the used QGIS?

I am looking to test new QGIS against these things:

- Certificates
- Proxy settings
- running domestic Plugins
- access to Databases
- access to an internal/external WMS, WFS, and WMTS (with/without username and password)
- opening a GeoPackage
- importing a DXF
- Python version

Currently these things are done manually. For example, open QGIS, import GeoPackage, check if everything okay, and close QGIS.

This article [Stable version of QGIS for administration with strict security policy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416315/stable-version-of-qgis-for-administration-with-strict-security-policy) helps me, but wraps QGIS versions and there release dates rather than their behavior and functionality.

I have an idea of a writing a standalone script that by means of the [`try except`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) statement will check freshly installed QGIS together with custom inputs.

---

**References:**

- [Writing a stand-alone PyQGIS script in Python 3.6 instead of 3.7?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301172/writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script-in-python-3-6-instead-of-3-7)
- [How can I discover the Python version in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222075/how-can-i-discover-the-python-version-in-qgis)
- [Importing paths for QGIS 3 standalone scripts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276902/importing-paths-for-qgis-3-standalone-scripts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do Python unit tests.

See the QGIS documentation about this : https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/developers_guide/unittesting.html

You can also find a lot of unit tests already written in the QGIS repo : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/tests/src/python

So, if you want to test the QGIS features in your company, you can copy the desired tests with test data, add tests for specific installed plugins.